how does the accessed bit microcode assist work?
When a mem access occurs and the accessed bit in the PT is 0, it triggers a microcode assist that walks the PT and sets the accessed bit in each level.
In oredr for the assist's code to write the accessed bit to the levels of the PT, it needs to know thier virtual addresses.
But the pointers in cr3 and to the next level in the PT have phisycal addresses.
So how does the assist's code gets the virtual addresses?

What makes you so sure the microcode needs the virtual addresses? The CPU could include uops to access physical addresses, which the assist could use. Microcode doesn't have to play by the same rules as regular code; the CPU can build in back doors for it.

Thats possible. If it is whats happening, you think there is also a magic uop to access guest physical addresses (for when using ept and the assist is triggered from a guest)? Thanks

The access used a virtual address, so I assume it's like a page fault where the fault handler can get the virtual address (from CR2 in that case).
It's microcode so the mechanism doesn't have to be architecturally visible.  But in general it's normal that a fault / trap handler can get some data from the thing that triggered it, including for microcode assists using some internal register.

Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. But my question wasn't about the virtual address of the original mem access, It was about the virtual adresses for the PT walk (assuming the assist needs them to write and don't use magic uops to access physical addresses)

@itamar: Oh.  Microcode (or special hardware) must do its atomic RMW using just the physical address.  There might not be any virtual mapping for the physical page containing the PTE / PDE / etc, and no reverse mapping data structure for it to look it up conveniently even if there does happen to be a mapping.  It would also be worse for performance and an increase in complexity to potentially have a TLB miss in the middle of a microcode assist to do something related to another TLB entry.
